# Meaning of (QWidget *parent = 0) in constructor MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

just a part of a usual structured class in Qt:

```
class MyClass  :  public QWidget           
{

Q_OBJECT

 public:

   MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
.
.
.
}
```

Looking at the constructor I don't understand the meaning of the parameter `(QWidget *parent = 0)` ? What does this mean?

greetings

Comment: BTW, you will almost certainly want to add "explicit" in front of your constructor declaration, i.e. `explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);` Otherwise, the compiler could decide to automatically cast a `QWidget` to a `MyClass`, which is almost certainly going to lead to incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0)` defines a constructor that can take a `QWidget*`.

You might be confused at the `= 0` part, which is C++ syntax for [default arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Default arguments allow you to use the function without having to specify that particular argument. In the case of this, you could call this constructor like this:

```
mc = MyClass();
```

And this is equivalent to calling:

```
mc = MyClass(0); // or MyClass(NULL)
```

And that means that `MyClass` object will have no parent `QWidget`, because `= 0` means the parent is a null pointer.

Comment: So, are we speaking here of parent objects instead of parent classes? I mean the class MyClass obviously has the parent QWidget and inherits from it.

Comment: @Streight - objects. Classes just define an interface, whereas your code is using objects/instances of them. Your `MyClass` inherits from the `QWidget` class, but it uses a pointer-to-a-`QWidget` for its `parent`.

Comment: I am just a little surprised. As far as I had understood c++ I thought a class inheriting from another would be the childclass and the class that is "passing over" it's content is the parent class (parent). As far as I understand you now the content of this code section is that `MyClass` inherits from `QWidget`, but does not accept it as a parent. Right?

Comment: @Streight - this is a different concept of parent. The `QWidget *parent` means which widget this object will be a child of. The child is drawn in that particular widget/window. For example, you can have a `QWindow` object, and a `QCanvas` widget. The canvas can be a child of that window, and it will be drawn in that window. This is not the same as C++'s object model and class inheritance.

Comment: Ok, I guess you are right then :)) . I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

When you construct a new MyClass, you give it a pointer to a QWidget that you want to be the parent of the new one. The `= 0` means that if you do not supply an argument, it will have no parent. Or, more strictly speaking, its parent pointer will be set to NULL.

Comment: Not speaking c++ and qt it was still apparent what this meant - parameter should be pointer to QWidget and if no paramater supplied use null (or 0) meaning nothing passed in

Comment: I just happen to be learning Qt right now and have been through all of this very recently. :)

Answer (score 4):

**First of all its good to use explicit keyword following constructor function like**

```
explicit MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0 );
```

By using explicit ,it means you will not be able to do an implicit assignment.

For better understanding lets take an example

Suppose you create a class MyInteger that takes an integer in the constructor. Then you can write something like this:

```
MyInteger integer = 5;
```

For simple classes, this can work ok, but when you have complex classes, implicit assignments can result in errors. Therefor it is best to have explicit assignments:

```
MyInteger integer = MyInteger(5);
```

This way you are sure that everything is correct. It's a safeguard.

**What about the statement "QWidget *parent = 0"!**

**What is that for?**

You define a constructor with a default value. The default value in this case means that there is no parent.
Assigning 0 to a pointer (in this case)

```
MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0)
```

means that you create a pointer to nothing. In any normal case, you want a pointer to point to a certain address in memory, like the address of a parent widget.
But when you don't want to set a parent widget for example, you can point to nothing. Be aware though when using the pointer, always check that it actually points to something (and preferably something correct) or don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

That's a **default parameter**. If no parameter is supplied, the one provided is used.